# Is there an R function or code that allows add new calculated rows to a dataframe

Tags: r, rowwise

I have a dataframe like this (top) but want the bottom one as output.

Example of before and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst1 <-  split(df1, df1$item) 
lapply(lst1, function(x) rbind(x, ...))
```

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
    group_split(item) %>%
    map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, ...))
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail to the "..."

Comment: @billrowe  It is just for the calculation you want to fill it up because from the question title it is not clear (`Is there an R function or code that allows add new calculated rows to a dataframe`)